# saving "generic" object graph (Dictionary,Array,String,etc) to defaults without encoding?

Tags: swift

Can a generic object root be natively saved to defaults?  I know that custom objects need be encoded, but I desire to have the graph written so that it could be manipulated via the plist editor. In my case my "object" is an array of Dictionary of "generic" types.

This is what I'm trying to ditch (a playlist model)

```
class PlayItem : NSObject,NSCoding {
    var name : String = "item"
    var link : NSURL = NSURL.init(string: "http://")!
    var rank = 0

    override init() {
        name = "item"
        link = NSURL.init(string: "http://")!
        super.init()
    }
    init(name:String, link:NSURL, rank:Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.link = link
        self.rank = rank
        super.init()
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
        self.link = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("link") as! NSURL
        self.rank = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("rank") as! Int
    }
    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name")
        aCoder.encodeObject(link, forKey: "link")
        aCoder.encodeObject(rank, forKey: "rank")
    }
}

class PlayList: NSObject {
    var name : String = "list"
    var list : Array <PlayItem> = Array()

    override init() {
        name = "list"
        list = Array <PlayItem> ()
        super.init()
    }

    init(name:String, list:Array <PlayItem>) {
        self.name = name
        self.list = list
        super.init()
    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("name") as! String
        self.list = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("link") as! Array
    }
    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(name, forKey: "name")
        aCoder.encodeObject(list, forKey: "list")
    }
}
```

so I would use ditch PlayList and PlayItem custom objects and use Array, Dictionary, String, etc to say be able to save something like this
[image]

the root would be my "playlists" array.  Am I correct that I can just save/read the entire playlists array as

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(playlists, forKey: "playlists")
playlists = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().arrayForKey: "playlists")
```

Comment: You can try [NSObject-ObjectMap](https://github.com/uacaps/NSObject-ObjectMap)

Comment: Well, that didn't appear to handle array of dictionary with arrays so I decided to stick with what I had for now. The main focus was plist user editing after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is my solution - to keep the custom objects internally but publish generic ones. Here we have an array controller and tableview per playlist and playitem - with its controller bound to playlist controller selection for "list", and a central playlist array object.

```
struct k {
    static let play = "play"
    static let item = "item"
    static let name = "name"
    static let list = "list"
    static let link = "link"
    static let rank = "rank"
}

//  cache playlists read and saved to defaults
var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
var playlists = [PlayList]()
var playCache = [PlayList]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.restorePlaylists(restoreButton)
}

override func viewWillAppear() {
    // cache our list before editing
    playCache = playlists
}

@IBOutlet weak var restoreButton: NSButton!
@IBAction func restorePlaylists(sender: NSButton) {
    if let playArray = defaults.arrayForKey(UserSetting.Playlists.userDefaultsKey) {

playlistArrayController.removeObjects(playlistArrayController.arrangedObjects as! [AnyObject])
        for playlist in playArray {
            let play = playlist as! Dictionary<String,AnyObject>
            let items = play[k.list] as! [Dictionary <String,AnyObject>]
            var list : [PlayItem] = [PlayItem]()
            for playitem in items {
                let item = playitem as Dictionary <String,AnyObject>
                let name = item[k.name] as! String
                let path = item[k.link] as! String
                let link = NSURL.init(string: path)
                let rank = item[k.rank] as! Int
                let temp = PlayItem(name:name, link:link!, rank:rank)
                list.append(temp)
            }
            let name = play[k.name] as! String
            let temp = PlayList(name: name, list: list)
            playlistArrayController.addObject(temp)
        }
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            self.playlistTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}

@IBOutlet weak var saveButton: NSButton!
@IBAction func savePlaylists(sender: AnyObject) {
    let playArray = playlistArrayController.arrangedObjects as! [PlayList]
    var temp = Array<AnyObject>()
    for playlist in playArray {
        var list = Array<AnyObject>()
        for playitem in playlist.list {
            let item : [String:AnyObject] = [k.name:playitem.name, k.link:playitem.link.absoluteString, k.rank:playitem.rank]
            list.append(item)
        }
        temp.append([k.name:playlist.name, k.list:list])
    }
    defaults.setObject(temp, forKey: UserSetting.Playlists.userDefaultsKey)
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

It seems to me you need to explicitly unravel each value when saving or restoring. A sheet is used to edit with a dismissController action which when Cancel, will simply restore the playlists array with playCache - initially captured before editing. The playlists are explicitly saved or restored by user action.